# "cannot move out of variable because it is borrowed" when rotating variables

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am writing a program that writes to a file and rotates the file it's writing to every now and then. When I check to rotate the file, I can't seem to change the file since it is borrowed by my struct. Even if I `drop` the instance of the struct, I can't seem to regain ownership of the file to rename it.
Here is my [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=fdb0eaf06e7e4f67c15e&version=stable):

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Write};
use std::mem::{drop};

pub struct FileStruct<W: Write> {
    pub writer: Option<W>,
}

impl <W: Write> FileStruct<W> {
    pub fn new(writer: W) -> FileStruct<W> {
        FileStruct {
            writer: Some(writer),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::create("tmp.txt").unwrap();
    let mut tmp = FileStruct::new(&mut file);
    loop {
        if true { //will be time based if check
            drop(tmp);
            drop(file);
            file = File::create("tmp2.txt").unwrap();
            tmp = FileStruct::new(&mut file);
        }
        // write to file
    }
}
```

I know I can get this to work by moving the file creation into the `new` function call of `FileStruct` instead of having an intermediate variable, `file`, but I would like to know why this method where I forcibly drop all the variables where all the variables references should be returned doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need `tmp` outside of the if-block? If you don't, then you could make sure that the borrow ends before re-assigning `file`.

Comment: I do. The idea is that I am writing data in the loop and the if block is to change the output file. The if block is meant for me to determine if I should change `file`.

Answer (score 7):

As [the `std::mem::drop` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) says,

> While this does call the argument's implementation of `Drop`, it will not release any borrows, as borrows are based on lexical scope.

So even if you call `drop`, `file` will remain borrowed nonetheless.

Comment: Here's some info on possible non-lexical scopes: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/811

Answer (score 3):

Dropping `tmp` does not "release the borrow" of `file` because borrowing is lexically scoped. It's "active" as long as the program execution is within the lexical scope that contains `tmp` even if you drop it. What you intended to do might be possible in the future if/once "non-lexical scopes" are supported. Until then, you can make it work with `RefCell`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::io::{ self, Write };

/// wraps a reference to a RefCell<W>
struct RefCellWriteRef<'a, W: 'a>(&'a RefCell<W>);

/// implement Write for when W is Write
impl<'a, W: Write + 'a> Write for RefCellWriteRef<'a, W> {
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let mut w = self.0.borrow_mut();
        w.write(buf)
    }
    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        let mut w = self.0.borrow_mut();
        w.flush()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let file: RefCell<Vec<u8>> = RefCell::new(Vec::new());
    // use RefCellWriteRef(&file) instead of &mut file
    let mut tmp = RefCellWriteRef(&file); 
    for iter in 0..10 {
        if iter == 5 {
            drop(tmp);
            file.borrow_mut().clear(); // like opening a new file
            tmp = RefCellWriteRef(&file);
        }
        tmp.write(b"foo").unwrap();
    }
    drop(tmp);
    println!("{}", file.borrow().len()); // should print 15
}
```

The trick here is that given a shared reference to a `RefCell<T>` you can (eventually) get a `&mut T` via `borrow_mut()`. The compile-time borrow checker is pleased because we only use a shared reference on the surface and it's OK to share `file` like that. Mutable aliasing is avoided by checking at runtime whether the internal `T` has already been mutably borrowed.