# How do I add references to a container when the borrowed values are created after the container?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

For reasons related to code organization, I need the compiler to accept the following (simplified) code:

```
fn f() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    let a = 0;
    vec.push(&a);
    let b = 0;
    vec.push(&b);
    // Use `vec`
}
```

The compiler complains

```
error: `a` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
4 |     vec.push(&a);
  |               - borrow occurs here
...
8 | }
  | ^ `a` dropped here while still borrowed
  |
  = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created

error: `b` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:8:1
  |
6 |     vec.push(&b);
  |               - borrow occurs here
7 |     // Use `vec`
8 | }
  | ^ `b` dropped here while still borrowed
  |
  = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

However, I'm having a hard time convincing the compiler to drop the vector before the variables it references. `vec.clear()` doesn't work, and neither does `drop(vec)`. `mem::transmute()` doesn't work either (to force `vec` to be `'static`).

The only solution I found was to transmute the reference into `&'static _`. Is there any other way? Is it even possible to compile this in safe Rust?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is it even possible to compile this in safe Rust?

No. What you are trying to do is **inherently unsafe** in the general case.

The collection contains a reference to a variable that will be dropped before the collection itself is dropped. This means that the destructor of the collection has access to references that are *no longer valid*. The destructor could choose to dereference one of those values, breaking Rust's memory safety guarantees.

> note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created

As the compiler tells you, you need to reorder your code. *You didn't actually say what the limitations are* for "reasons related to code organization", but the straight fix is:

```
fn f() {
    let a = 0;
    let b = 0;
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(&a);
    vec.push(&b);
}
```

A less obvious one is:

```
fn f() {
    let a;
    let b;

    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    a = 0;
    vec.push(&a);
    b = 0;
    vec.push(&b);
}
```

---

That all being said, once [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) are enabled, your original code will work! The borrow checker becomes more granular about how long a value needs to live.

But *wait*; I just said that the collection might access invalid memory if a value inside it is dropped before the collection, and now the compiler is allowing that to happen? What gives?

This is because the standard library pulls a sneaky trick on us. Collections like `Vec` or `HashSet` guarantee that they do not access their generic parameters in the destructor. They communicate this to the compiler using the [unstable `#[may_dangle]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/34761) feature.

See also:

- [Moved variable still borrowing after calling `drop`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43428894/155423)
- ["cannot move out of variable because it is borrowed" when rotating variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34007692/155423)

Comment: Basically, computing values and pushing them are dependant on the same condition for the same value, but different values have different conditions, so your first case means duplicating `if` statements. The values can't be moved into the vector because the vector must contain references to trait objects. But your last case is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: I always did wonder if there was any practical purpose to the `let a;` syntax.

Comment: @BHustus see [another example that's probably even more useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220053/155423).