# Inserting references to variables into HashSet then using variables afterwards

Tags: rust

I am trying insert pairs of a variable into a `HashSet`, after checking if the pair is present already. I then need to do downstream work with the pair, within the same context. Here is a playground reproducing my problem:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5eecfa9c1e54b468d79955aab916dd84&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut h = HashSet::new();
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    if h.contains(&(&a, &b)) {
        println!("fail");
    }
    h.insert(&(&a, &b));
}
```

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:15
   |
10 |     h.insert(&(&a, &b));
   |               ^^^^^^^^ - temporary value dropped here while still borrowed
   |               |
   |               temporary value does not live long enough
11 | }
   | - temporary value needs to live until here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime

error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:17
   |
10 |     h.insert(&(&a, &b));
   |                 ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
11 | }
   | - `a` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created

error[E0597]: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |     h.insert(&(&a, &b));
   |                     ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
11 | }
   | - `b` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

How can I check if `a` and `b` are in the set, then insert them afterwards if they are not, and then do other things with them? How are they being borrowed if I am loading in a reference to them within the same scope?

Comment: Are your values actually integers? If so, it seems like you'd be better served by not using references to begin with. e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9e6af44a5bc1c335664c779a4b1586ca&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015

Comment: *How are they being borrowed if I am loading in a reference to them* — that's what borrowing **is**: taking a reference to a value.

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] your question to expand on what part of the error message you are having trouble with? "values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created" feels clear to me.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How do I add references to a vector when the borrowed values are created after the vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44987555/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The combination of `h.contains(&(&a, &b))` and `h.insert(&(&a, &b))` is suspicious. Normally you would call `insert` with a `T` and `contains` with a reference-to-`T`. It still works the way you wrote it (well, it would, if you follow the answer to the question Shepmaster linked) but the compiler infers that you want a `HashSet<&(&i32, &i32)>` when you probably wanted a `HashSet<(&i32, &i32)>`. (Or if loganfsmyth is correct, you really want `HashSet<(i32, i32)>` and no references at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Leaving "why"s aside for a moment, the example as presented has three issues:

1. The tuple `&(...)` *ceases to exist* once the function call ends. So inserting a reference to something that will not exist once `HashSet::insert` returns is an error, and one that the compiler thankfully catches.
2. You declared the `HashSet` before the variables you want to reference, which the compiler sees as an error (likely due to the fact that, at some point in the `HashSet`'s scope, the variables `a` and `b` do not exist). This is something I've been burnt by on numerous occasions and is a limitation you should keep in mind until the compiler improves.
3. As pointed out in the comments above, `HashSet`s take `T` when inserting and `&T` when accessing. Your code uses `T` for both.

The following code fixes these issues:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let mut h = HashSet::new();
    if h.contains(&(&a, &b)) {
        println!("fail");
    }
    h.insert((&a, &b));
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4d2a2150f719a92f0eed105a92e3d227&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Compare the lines that declare the `HashSet` and insert the tuple.

Comment: @Shepmaster [With NLLs, the compiler can shorten the lifetime of `h` so that it doesn't outlive `a` and `b`.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=353742ca6fc1b8d4fcf63eb6af92ff9f&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018)

Comment: @trentcl hmm. I'll investigate more into the why on that and update the linked question. Thanks for pointing that out! I'll remove my incorrect comment.

Comment: @trentcl I updated the linked question. Pedantically, `h` still outlives `a` and `b` (and it always "could"). Compiler nuances are tough.